# Джойн последней записи

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Есть две таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE main (
  ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  .........
);

CREATE TABLE child (
  ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  MAIN_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  .........
);
```

Нужно вытащить записи из `main` по каким-то фильтрам и приджойнить к ним соответствующие последние (`MAX(ID)`) записи из `child`. Сответствующих записей может не быть.

Как бы это оптимальней сделать? Сейчас с клиента посылается запрос на выборку нужных записей из `main`. А потом в цикле для каждой записи выполняется еще один запрос

```
SELECT * FROM child WHERE main_id = ?
ORDER BY id DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Что-то оптимальнее можно придумать?

Записей в main не более 300. Записей в child очень много. В пределе каждые 2-5 секунд будет добавляться по одной записи в child на каждую запись main

Comment: Какая версия ? в 12c говорят появился lateral join

Comment: В итоговой выборке должны быть вообще все существующие main_id или что то (бОльшая часть) еще фильтруется в where ?

Comment: @Mike 12c. Из child не фильтруется ничего. Фильтры накладываются только на записи из main

Comment: Если фильтры накладываются на main, значит и из child выбирается далеко не все, а только для тех записей, которые остались от main. А от того сколько их осталось, подход может кардинально различаться. Если выбирается более 50% main становится выгоден `select main_id, max(id) from child group by main_id` и подклейка его к запросу. Если менее 50%, то тогда lateral (при его наличии). Для начала попробуйте вот тот свой запрос одной записи из child поместить в `lateral join` к запросу из main. Из lateral join, если он у вас работает, можно обращаться к id из main

Comment: И еще интересен план выполнения на `select max(id) from child where main_id=?` (если full scan, то желательно еще проверить при наличии составного индекса main_id, id)

Comment: @Mike при составном индексе получается `INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX)`. При LATERAL мой исходный запрос дает `TABLE ACCESS FULL` на child

Comment: Попробуйте вариант в ответе. если подзапрос child_id пойдет с тем же планом, что поиск одиного max(id) то все будет отлично

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой запрос получился

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  main m
  LEFT JOIN child c ON (
    c.id = (SELECT MAX(c.id) FROM child c WHERE c.main_id = m.id)
  )
```

С составным индексом `child (main_id, id)`

Answer (score 3):

Такой вариант с корреляционным подзапросом, также заслуживает внимания:

```
select *
from main m
outer apply (
    select *
    from child c 
    where c.id = (select max (id) from child where main_id = m.id)
) 
where 1 = 1 -- some conditions here
```

Comment: По плану получился один в один с моим

Comment: Ну да, пока один в один, надо сравнить на реальных данных. ID  в обоих таблицах действительно не PK?

Comment: main.id и child.id - PK

Comment: Тогда попробуйте ещё с несоставным индексом `child (main_id)` и условие `c.main_id = m.id` убрать. А то два индекса по одной колонке как-то затратно.

Comment: Тогда по child  TABLE ACCESS FULL

Comment: Странно, ещё раз проверил, всё в порядке - INDEX RANGE SCAN. Может записей ещё мало? Я генерировал каждому из 300 папаш 1000 сынков.

Comment: У меня один папа и 279 000 детей

Comment: Попробовал с 1:300000, оба запроса, ваш и мой, примерно одинаковы и оба берут индексы.

Comment: При отстутствии составного? Просто два индекса `child.id` (PK) и `child.main_id`?

Comment: Ничего не пойму. Создал две таблицы полностью идентичной структуры, залил туда данные из основных `SORT AGGREGATE/TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED/INDEX RANGE SCAN` выполняю на моих таблицах `SORT AGGREGATE/TABLE ACCESS FULL`

Comment: А к чему первый фрагмент плана, а чему второй?

Comment: Первый на новых таблицах. Второй на основных

Comment: Проверьте индексы. Вы же вчера меняли их и жаловались, что full scan.

Answer (score 1):

При условии отбора из main не всех записей можно применить что нибудь такое:

```
select *
  from (
    select main.*, (select max(id) from child where main_id=main.id) child_id
      from main
  ) m
  left join child on child.id=m.child_id
```

Comment: Наверное да. Немного смущает `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN` на child, но возможно это от того, что сейчас у меня в main одна запись

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Возможно, сложно судить. оракл вполне мог поменять мнение если main весь. а мог действительно из за одной записи.

Comment: Засунул агрегирующий подзапрос в условие джойн и получилось загляденье. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    `t1` .*,
    `t2_data`.`some_f`
FROM
    `table1` AS `t1`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        MAX(`t2`.`some_field`) AS `some_f`, `t2`.`some_id`
    FROM
        `table2` AS `t2`
    GROUP BY
        `t2`.`some_id`) AS `t2_data` ON
    t2_data.some_id = t1.some_id
WHERE any condition
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ваш  запрос не рабочий, потому , что он для MySQL. Если его перевести в диалект Oracle, то получится точная копия ответа, который дал сам ТС. Лучше удалите это сообщение, т.к. никакой новой информации в этом топике оно не принсит.